# C# Passing Mock Object to Class That Verifies/Checks Parameter Type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, inheritance, mocking

I have a generic class called `SqlDataImporter` that reads data from a SQL data source. Here is some of its methods:

```
        #region properties

        protected IDbConnection DbConnection; // Maintain this connection
        protected IDataReader DataReader; // Used to import data via the DbConnection
        protected DataTable DataSegment;

        #endregion

        #region constructors

        protected SqlDataImporter(IDbConnection importConnection, string importQuery)
        {
            ValidateConstructorArguments(importConnection, importQuery); // throws exception if invalid

            this.DbConnection = importConnection;

            InitialiseDataReader(importQuery);
        }

        #endregion

        #region methods

        protected void ValidateConstructorArguments(IDbConnection importConnection, string importQuery)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(importQuery))
            {
                string msg = "Provided importQuery has null or empty value. A query must be provided for importing data.";
                throw new ArgumentException(msg);
            }
        }

        private void InitialiseDataReader(string importQuery)
        {
            if (this.DbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                this.DbConnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand command = this.DbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 1200;
                command.CommandText = importQuery;

                this.DataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }

            if (this.DataReader == null) // only reason this could happen is source doesn't exist?
                throw new Exception("Source does not exist: " + importQuery);
        }
```

The idea is that this class is generic enough to read from both a Postgresql data source (using an ODBCConnection passed) and a Sql Server data source (using a SqlConnection passed). The type of connection passed dictates the type of `IDataReader` created because of the content of the `InitialiseDataReader()` method.

I then created 2 child classes `PostgreSqlImporter` and `SqlServerImporter` to be used when reading from different sources. They both inherit from this parent class. In reality, all the work is done in the parent `SqlDataImporter` class in an effort to reduce duplication.

All the child classes do is call this ValidateConstructorArguments() method and verify the passed Connections are of the expected type (OdbcConnnection or SqlConnection depending on the class). For Example:

```
 public SqlServerImporter(IDbConnection importConnection, string importQuery) : base(importConnection,  importQuery)
        {
            ValidateConstructorArguments(importConnection);
        }



        protected void ValidateConstructorArguments(IDbConnection importConnection)
        {
            if (importConnection.GetType() != typeof(SqlConnection))
            {
                string msg = "Provided importConnection must be of type SqlConnection. Actual type is " + importConnection.GetType();
                throw new ArgumentException(msg);
            }
        }
```

Originally I made the connection parameter the generic type `IDBConnection` because I wanted the ability to pass a Mock object as a param from my Unit Tests. But now I've added this code to verify the type of the connection passed (`ValidateConstructorArguments(IDbConnection importConnection)`) I get my own ArgumentException thrown when I pass the mocked object: `System.ArgumentException: Provided importConnection must be of type SqlConnection. Actual type is Castle.Proxies.IDbConnectionProxy`

I'm lost now. I want to still be able to pass Mock objects for testing but can't verify the runtime type of the connection if I want to do so. If I scrap verifying the type of the connection, then I wonder if there's any point to having these two child classes (PostgreSqlImport & SqlServerImporter).

- Should I scrap the two child classes and the verification of the connection type at runtime? Doesn't seem robust doing this...
- Should I add code to the `ValidateConstructorArguments` method to ignore the type if it is a mock type?
- Is my design flawed?

Comment: What type of driver do you plan to use?  ODBC and OleDb are different generic specification for interface to databases.  I'm not sure what type the Net SQLClient uses.  For SQLclient you can have a number of different types of drivers (see : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).  I think you need to define a driver which will return the type.

Comment: @jdweng going a bit past my knowledge but I'm planning on ODBC all the way because it's been used before in the codebase. 

I'm not sure what defining a driver which returns the type would look like. Keep in mind the plan is for this code to exist in a SSIS Script Task with limit libraries and dependencies.